# Poweredge Sc1425 wont boot after install

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, dell-poweredge

I'm trying to install ESXi 4 on a PowerEdge SC1425. I have the Bios set as SATA drives as opposed RAID as the install doesn't detect the raid, I've told it to install on drive 0 and everyhting appears to install OK but when it reboots and I remove the install cd it fails to boot saying 'No Boot Device Available'. The bios is set to boot from IDE CDRom and then what it terms C Drive, hard drive priority is 0 and then 1.

I have had a search can cannot find anything matching the installing ok but not booting scenario.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that model server is on the VMware HCL, so you may not be able to get it installed.

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=search&deviceCategory=server&productId=1&advancedORbasic=advanced&maxDisplayRows=1000000&key=&release%5B%5D=-1&datePosted=-1&partnerId%5B%5D=23&formFactorId%5B%5D=-1&filterByEVC=0&filterByFT=0&min_sockets=&min_cores=&min_memory=&rorre=0